# find value inside array and print if data exists

Tags: php

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1                               
            [name] => Jacob
            [email] => jac@xyz.com
            [type] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 21                              
            [name] => Agile
            [email] => agi@xyz.com
            [type] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 23                              
            [name] => Sam
            [email] => same@xyz.com
            [type] => 3
        )
)

foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    if(($value['type'] == 1 || $value['type'] ==2) && $value['type'] != 3) {
        echo "lost because 3 exists there."
    }
}
```

I would like to find if in this array type 3 does not exist but type 1,2 exist
I would like a condition where type 1 or type 2 is acceptable but it type 3 exist it should say lost because of 3 exists.

Answer (score 0):

try to in your condition

```
if(array_search(3, array_column($users, 'type'))){
    echo "lost because 3 exists there."
}
```